# If child class exist then add class to parent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On page scroll new class is added to a child and if the class is added to the child then also a new class should be added to the parent.

This is my code (wrapped like this because of the Drupal framework):

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.myClasses = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

 if($("#navigation").hasClass("stickynav-active")){
    $("#header-wrapper").addClass("sticky-active");
 }

  }
};
})(jQuery);
```

`#header-wrapper` is the parent. If I scroll down the `stickynav-active` is added (by some module) to `#navigation` so it starts existing after scrolling down, but my code doesn't add `sticky-active` to `#header-wrapper`?

Comment: so sounds like you need to bind to scroll event or look into mutation observer or change the code that adds the class in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone suggested to wrap it in a scroll event.

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.myClasses = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {


$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($("#navigation").hasClass("stickynav-active")){
         $("#header-wrapper").addClass("sticky-active");
    }
    else {
        $("#header-wrapper").removeClass("sticky-active");
    }
});


  }
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because jQuery didn't listen to the event when you add the class `stickynav-active` to `#navigation`...

Why don't you try to add `sticky-active` to `#header-wrapper` in the same function that you add the class `stickynav-active` to `#navigation`?